# In yum, what is presto?

Tags: linux, installation, fedora, yum

When I do a `yum install` or a `yum update`, sometimes I get this

```
Loaded plugins: presto, refresh-packagekit
```

telling me that the packages are being updated.

What is **presto**?

Comment: Only in a geek community could you ask a question like this without people questioning your sanity. ;-) I have no idea what you are asking, but my first instinct was to open up the question so I could find out what yum and presto are. Sure enough there are several excellent answers with links to explain both.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presto makes yum download only the delta. The changes. It downloads them and apply them on the existing data, thus it saves a lot of bandwidth. (You pay with Disk IO and CPU load instead.)

It is a really good thing for developing countries, people with mobile internet and so on.

ps.: OpenSUSE been using this for a long time. If I remember clearly they were the first RPM based delta users, but fixme, I'm not sure about this. (openSUSE downloads delta, apply, install package. On Fedora: Download all delta, apply them, install them all.)

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/FeaturePresto

Comment: beaten by 20 seconds >.<

Comment: Sorry man... :D

Comment: The extra disk IO and CPU load is negligible compared to the bandwidth saving.

Comment: Indeed. I just wanted to say you pay with those. Like some admin said: "Currently, bandwidth is cheaper". That's why some smaller distro won't ship this since they dont have enough resource on the servers.

Answer (score 3):

It adds support for **delta-RPMs** which use a delta-transfer algorithm to save time downloading. Basically, **presto** won't download the entire package, only the changes since the last version.

[Fedora Wiki](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/FeaturePresto#DeltaRPM_Support_.28Presto.29):

> The presto plugin for yum adds support for downloading deltarpms and using them to generate new packages. If user enables this plugin, it will make a substantial dent in the amount of data having to be downloaded for updates.

Comment: Delta-RPM, not deb. Fedora uses RPM.

Comment: @Sathya: Whoops, fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Presto is a plugin which enables Delta RPM support in yum. Basically, deltaRPM creates a new RPM based on the diffs of the new and previous version - saving on bandwidth and time required  to download, since only the "changed" bits will be downloaded, instead of the full monolithic package.

More details:

- [Fedora Features/Presto](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/FeaturePresto)
- [Delta RPM FreshMeat page](http://freshmeat.net/projects/deltarpm/)